# Insert multiple users and groups in a user field of a Sharepoint Online list using Pnp-Js-Core

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, pnp-js-core, insert-update-listitem

How can I insert multiple users and groups in a user field of a Sharepoint Online list using Pnp-Js-Core?

greetings and thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use it as below:

```
$pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Test").items.add({
    Title: "test",    
    MultiUserId: { 
        results: [ 9, 6 ]  // User/Groups ids as an array of numbers
    }
}).then(i => {
    console.log(i);
});
```

You need to pass an array of user ids or group ids.

Also, if your internal column name is `MultiUser` you need to set the column name as `MultiUserId` i.e append `Id` to your internal column name.

Also, ensure that your column settings are set as below:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Check the PnP Js documentation Work with Items [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items)

User field will set the value based on the user/group id, very similiar with lookup field:

```
pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle("PeopleFields").items.add({
    Title: Util.getGUID(),
    User1Id: 9, // allows a single user
    User2Id: { 
        results: [ 16, 45 ] // allows multiple users
    }
}).then(i => {
    console.log(i);
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but in the results array, I insert the user IDs, how do I insert the groups as well?

Comment: set group is the same to user, you can specify a group id in the above result array.

Comment: Beware that the above does not apply to later versions of sppnp.